# citations without round brackets

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am compiling my thesis using MIT thesis template (http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/), which uses the `apalike` package for the bibliography style.  All my citation in the text show up within round brackets. Is there a way to make refs without brackets

The aim is to have "This has been shown by Levin, 2004", not "This has been shown by (Levin, 2004)"

Comment: Welcome, please add a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to your question. This way, we can reproduce your issue. Right now, you are giving confusing information.

Comment: If you use `apalike`, you are probably not using `biblatex`. So the body of your question and your tagging seem to contradict each other. You can avoid any confusion, by adding an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) to your question, so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: There is no *package* named `apalike` -- at least not in the TeXlive distribution. (There is, however, a package called `apacite`.) Are you maybe referring to the *bibliography style* named `apalike`? Separately, please advise if you use any citation management packages, say, `natbib`.

Comment: if you are indeed using biblatex as from your title, you are probably using the generic`\cite{}` command instead of the context specific ones. But without an mwe it is hard to be sure. At a guess you should use `\textcite{}` in this context.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using the mit template to compile my thesis in latex (http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/). I assumed that Biblatex was inbuilt but found that was not the case- sorry about the confusion.  What it uses is BibTex.  My problem remains the same- that I cant get rid of brackets around the citations.

Comment: This sound stupid, but I am unable to add/attach/paste a mwe. Can someone please tell me how to do that!

Comment: Since you don't use `biblatex`, I have removed the tag. You should be able to edit your question and then you can just paste the plain text of your MWE (make sure it is really minimal).

Answer (score 2):

Without a MWE it is hard to tell what's going wrong, but I assume you are using the wrong command to cite and are using the `natbib` package. I believe you are using `\citep`, which adds **p**arentheses, whereas `\cite` should do what you are looking for. If you weren't using this package, this might be a solution for you.

Edit: prividing an MWE. LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} %More control for citations, adding BiBTeX compatibility.
\begin{document}
Using citep gives: \citep{mwe}.

Using cite gives: \cite{mwe}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

.bib file used: test.bib

```
@misc{mwe,
author = {JiyuuSensei},
year = {2016},
title = {Minimal Working Example}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I believe the OP wants "Jones, year" as the citation call-out style, not "Jones (year)". To get the former style, use `\citealp`, not `\citet`.

Comment: MWE:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\typein [\files]{Enter file names to process, (chap1,chap2 ...), or `all' to process all files:}
\def\all{all}
\ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi

\begin{document}
\include{cover}
\include{contents}
\include{chap1}
\appendix  
\include{App}  
\include{biblio}  
\end{document}

Comment: my biblio file is a tex file with the following content: \begin{singlespace}
\bibliography{main}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{singlespace}                                                                                   The 'main' file is a .bib file with following preamble followed by all the references                                                                    @preamble{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} "
 # "\newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1} "
 # "\newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} "
 # "\newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1} " }

Comment: Sorry, just not able to add a formatted mwe. Tried all possible ways, including pasting as plain text, but just cant get the line breaks. Hope you can still make sense of this and help me.

Comment: Using this code, all chapters of my thesis gets generated in the compiled pdf along with the bibliography. The only problem is that all citations appear within round brackets.   If I use natbib in this code (\usepackage[round]{natbib}), the pdf still gets generated with ? in place of all references in the text and no bibliography.